# Yum broken on RHEL 7; "[Errno 12] Timeout on ..." repository

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm

Issue and symptoms:

```
[root@XXX ~]# yum install python-pip
Loaded plugins: enabled_repos_upload, langpacks, package_upload, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager

epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                |  16 kB  00:00:00
epel                                                                                                                                | 5.3 kB  00:00:00
https://XXX/pulp/repos/BMO_Org_01/Library/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/extras/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on https://XXX/pulp/repos/BMO_Org_01/Library/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/extras/os/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received')
Trying other mirror.
https://XXX/pulp/repos/BMO_Org_01/Library/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/extras/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on https://XXX/pulp/repos/BMO_Org_01/Library/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/extras/os/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received')
Trying other mirror.
https://XXX/pulp/repos/BMO_Org_01/Library/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/extras/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on https://XXX/pulp/repos/BMO_Org_01/Library/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/extras/os/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received')
Trying other mirror.
```

I have replaced my machine name with "XXX" in the output above.

This would go on and output similar logs when trying other repos.

It does seem like my machine have access to the internet via proxy:

```
[root@TBRISCCLPRAPP05 ~]# nslookup google.com
Server:         10.254.90.97
Address:        10.254.90.97#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.164.206
Name:   google.com
Address: 2607:f8b0:400b:80f::200e
```

I have exported the appropriate HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables.

Machine info:

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.7 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
```

Comment: nslookup server reply won't be used as a proxy, it's just the DNS server.
You can perhaps try `yum clean all` before anything else.

Comment: Seems like a proxy problem, could you try `wget -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=<proxy url> <yum url>`?

Comment: You say that you've replaced 'my machine name' with XXX; do you mean that the system seems unable to connect to a repo that's hosted on the same machine?

Comment: If your machine `XXX` is local, then you're not going to reach it via the proxy. You need to unset those. It sounds asisnine, but you only need the proxy variables when you need to go through the proxy; so use aliases, functions, wrapper scripts and what have you to control that. Then if you're using Gnome, set it there in system proxy settings. If you have external yum repos, set the proxy per-repo in `/etc/yum.repos.d/<external>` using `proxy=user@host:port`. I'd write this up as an answer but there's too big of an "if" that this depends on.

Comment: I tried `yum clean all` , when I re-run `yum install python-pip` I get this:  ` One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown)` error. How do I find out which repo is invalid?

Comment: mehlj: I tried looking into /etc/yum.repos.d and picked the first url and ran `wget -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=<proxy url> <yum url>`, this is output I got: `Resolving XXX (XXX)... XX.XXX.XX.XX
Connecting to XXX (XXX)|XX.XXX.XX.XX|:XXX... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.
` XXX is my machine and XX.XXX.XX.XX is my machine's IP

Comment: OK so I found out my epel repo was invalid. I disabled it by running `rpm -e epel-release` and then tries to reinstall by running `yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm` but I got a `Error: Nothing to do`

Comment: Just wanted to give everybody an update. There were multiple issues: 1) the original issues where I was getting timed out from the red hat repos, that was for some reason due to going through a proxy, when I removed the proxy settings, all those repos were accessible, I was wrong that those repos were local, instead they exist somewhere inside my firm 2) When I needed external libraries from a web url (like epel-release), that requires proxy setting, but with proxy settings it makes the red hat repos not accessible so I ended up disabling red hat repos when an external URL is required

Comment: I am not sure how to mark this as resolved